# Fun with riddles

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple riddle program that reads a text file of riddles, stores that into an ArrayList, then reads a text file of answers to the riddles, and stores that into an ArrayList. Well, so far so good. My problem is, whenever the user answers one of the riddles, it's supposed to give a point for the correct answer, and nothing for the wrong answer. I tested it out, answered the riddle correctly, however the program instead said it was wrong. Now, some of the answers should accept more than 1 as the correct answer, for instance: 
Q: What has eyes but cannot see?
A: A potatoe, a storm, a needle.
Let's say the user didn't think of 3 but just 1, and it was storm. I want the program to read storm and since it is contained in the answer for that, then it's correct. Here's my code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/* Array of riddles with a separate array of answers */
class RiddlesProgram 
{
public RiddlesProgram(){} //Empty constructor

public void riddleGame() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String ridFile = "Riddles.txt";
    String ansFile = "Answers.txt";
    Scanner ridReader = new Scanner(new File(ridFile));
    Scanner ansReader = new Scanner(new File(ansFile));
    /** ArrayLists for riddles and answers */
    ArrayList<String> riddles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
    /** Reading the Riddles & storing them in their array */
    while(ridReader.hasNext())
    {
        riddles.add(ridReader.nextLine());
    }ridReader.close();
    /** Reading the Answers & storing them in their array */
    while(ansReader.hasNext())
    {
        answers.add(ansReader.nextLine());
    }ansReader.close();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = "";
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Riddler!"); 
    System.out.println("Let's start answering riddles..."); System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Each riddle will require either a one word answer, or multiple word answer.");
    System.out.println("Example: \nQ: How much would could a wood chuck, chuck?\n"
            + "A: As much wood as a wood chuck could chuck if a wood chuck would chuck wood.");
    int count = 1;
    int points = 0;
    while(count!=16)
    {
        System.out.println("Riddle # " + count);
        System.out.println(riddles.get(count));
        System.out.println("\nAnswer? ");
        answer = in.nextLine();
        if(answers.contains(answer.toLowerCase()))
        {
            System.out.println("Correct! + 1 point.");
            points += 1;
        }//End if
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong! No points!");
        }//End else
        count++;
    }//End while
}//End riddlegame
}//End class
```

Sample riddle text
I am lighter than a feather, yet no man can hold me for very long. What am I?
Three guys run into a bar, the fourth man ducks. Why does he duck?
How do you put a giraffe in a refrigerator?
How do you put an elephant in a refrigerator?
All of the animals go to a meeting for the Lion King. One animal doesnt show up. Which animal doesn't come?
You come to a river that aligators live in. There is no boat, raft, bridge, nor material to make them. How do you get accross?
A fifteen foot rope is tied to a horse. The horse is 25 feet from a stack of hay. How can the horse get to the hay?
From what number can you take half and leave nothing?
How can you drop an egg 3 feet without breaking it?
How can you make a fire with only one stick?
How can you tell the difference between a can of chicken soup and a can of tomato soup?
Can giraffes have babies?
What has four wheels and flies?
Feed me and I live, give me something to drink and I'll die. What am I?
What has eyes but cannot see?
When is a door not a door?

Sample answer text
Breath
He didn't want to hit the bar
Open the door, put him in, close the door
Open the door, take the giraffe out, put him in, close the door
The elephant, he's in the refrigerator
Jump in, swim accross, get out. The aligators are at the meeting
The rope isn't tied to anything but the horse
8. Take the top half away and the "o" is left
Drop it 4 feet, the first 3 feet the egg won't hit anything
Make sure it's a matchstick
Read the label
No, they have giraffes
A dumpster
Fire
A needle, a potatoe, a storm, or true lovers
When it's ajar

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add Riddles.txt and Answers.txt.

Comment: Try to print `answer.toLowerCase()` and the content of `answers` and you will see what's going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`answers` does not contain the string `"storm"`. It contains a string which contains `"storm"`. Retrieve the corresponding string from `answers` before checking `String#contains(String)` (rather than `List#contains(Object)`, as you're doing now).

```
String correctAnswer = answers.get(count).toLowerCase();
if(correctAnswer.contains(answer.toLowerCase()))
{
    System.out.println("Correct! + 1 point.");
    points += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that... With that I can figure out how to make it where it will also accept extra text as long as it includes the correct answer. I suck with words, but for example: 
A: Get the cat, drag him out, run. is the correct answer, 
but user enters:
Get the cat and drag him out then run.